# Mac OS: Docker-Machine CLI deprecated in favour of Docker Desktop, but where is its functionality?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I am running Mac OS 11.6 and since the introduction of Docker Desktop I have not been able to find functionality that used to be in `docker-machine` and which is indispensable to me. For example, I need to connect myself to a remote docker host. I can't find any view in Docker desktop which lists the remote containers. I used to do this with the command `docker-machine list`. Where can I find this list in Docker Desktop? Where can I connect myself to it like I would do with `docker-machine env <name_of_my_remote_host>` so I can then run commands like `docker-compose build`?

---

I've lost functionality that is essential to me and can't find where it went, and I am getting conflicting information in the net.

On the one hand, I am told that docker-machine is deprecated and I am to use Docker Desktop, and on the other hand there are SO threads that say, install it with brew or via curl. So it's deprecated but even @DavidMaze says in his comment "you don't **usually** need `docker-machine`...", which means that it is needed if you want to do some things, or in other words: Docker Desktop does not completely replace the docker-machine functionality.

Comment: You don't usually need `docker-machine`, unless you're trying to manually set up a Docker VM outside the Docker Desktop environment (perhaps your employer has concerns about the Desktop licensing).  It's still available from sources like Homebrew if you do need it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't understand your answer. Maybe my question isn't worded clearly. I need to connect to a **remotely** running Docker container and update it. Usually I do that by issuing the command `docker-machine env my_remote_docker_host` and then `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`. Please tell me where I can do this using Docker Desktop. (My impression so far is that all you can use Docker Desktop for is to look at local containers and stop or start them.)

Comment: [The source repository still exists](https://github.com/docker/machine) and I can still `brew install docker-machine`.  Or you can directly set `$DOCKER_HOST` and [other environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables) (which is all `docker-machine env` really does).  I gather [Docker contexts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/context_create/) fill this need on current tooling, though I've never used them.  For this task I might use Ansible, Salt Stack, or a similar generic system-management tool.

Comment: if you want a similar and maintained tech without all the Docker For desktop cruft or licensing, you could use minikube to run your docker machines locally, as all of the machines come with a docker service you can access locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to connect to a remotely running Docker container and update it. Usually I do that by issuing the command `docker-machine env my_remote_docker_host` and then `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`.

You don't need `docker-machine` to connect to a remote host that's running docker. For a one-off, you can specify the value of `DOCKER_HOST` (which is one of the values `docker-machine` is setting when you configure the environment):

```
DOCKER_HOST=ssh://user@host.example.com docker ps
```

If you plan to do this often, have a look at [`docker context`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/context_create/):

```
docker context create host-a --docker host=ssh://user@host-a
docker context use host-a
docker ps
```